# Troubleshooting AJAX XMLHTTP object creation

Tags: javascript, ajax

Troubleshooting this function and having trouble finding an error with it as the ajax stuff is all copy-pasted from a guide I'm following:

```
function updateStuff() {

    // Data validation for a text var called val

    var xmlHttp ;

    if(window.ActiveXObject){  
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e)
            xmlHttp = false;
    }else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp)
        alert("Error : Cannot create xmlHttp object");
    else{
        alert("Worked");
        //xmlHttp.open("GET","update.php?val="+val,true);
        //xml.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        //xmlHttp.send();           
        }
    }   
}
```

Right now I'm just trying to get the "Worked" alert to display at the end of the if-statement. I know the JS is all linked correctly because if I take all the ajax out the data validation works properly with alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to troubleshoot this, try:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject) {  
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.name + " " + e.message);
        xmlHttp = false;
} else {
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.name + " " + e.message);
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}
```

The idea to figure out what the errors actually are. Once you are out of the try / catch, you loose track of what went wrong.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you, however I forgot to mention that I tried putting an alert right after `var xmlHTTP;` and not even that popped up.

Comment: Try using the debugger in F12 tools. Set breakpoints in the browser and prevent coding yourself mad.

Comment: UGH F12 just showed me my extra curly brace that was messing everything up...wow what a noob move. Thanks for the tip though beautifulcoder I hadn't thought of that.